# If $f$ is integrable, then for $p < \infty$, $\int f^p <\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

To be $f_n \in L^p$, it should satisfy $\int_E |f_n|^p < \infty$.   I understand that $\varphi_n$ is integrable since it is dominated by an integrable function $g$. But, does this imply that for $q <\infty$,  $\int_E |f_n|^p = \int_E |\varphi_n|^{q-1} <\infty$ ?

In general, if some exponents, $p$, are finite, does this imply that $\int_E f^p < \infty$ for an integrable $f$?

I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: you're generalizing too much. $f_n$ has the same magnitude as $\varphi_n^{q-1}$, so $f_n \in L^p$ iff $\varphi_n^{q-1} \in L^p$, but $\varphi_n^{q-1}$ is simple, so of course it's in $L^p$.

Comment: What do you mean by "magnitude"?

Comment: $|f_n| = |\varphi_n^{q-1}|$